# ASP MVC: When is IController Dispose() called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, garbage-collection, idisposable

I'm going through a big refactoring / speed tweaking of one of my larger MVC apps.  It has been deployed to production for a few months now, and I was starting to get timeouts waiting for connections in the connection pool.  I have tracked the issue down to the connections not getting disposed properly.

In light of that, I have since made this change to my base controller:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    private ConfigurationManager configManager;  // Manages the data context.

    public MyBaseController()
    {
         configManager = new ConfigurationManager();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.configManager != null)
            {
                this.configManager.Dispose();
                this.configManager = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. **Am I introducing a race condition?** Since the `configManager` manages the `DataContext` that exposes `IQueryable<>` parameters to
   the views,  I need to make sure that `Dispose()` will not be called
   on the controller before the view finishes rendering.
2. **Does the MVC framework call `Dispose()` on the Controller before or after the view is rendered?  Or, does the MVC framework leave that
   up to the GarbageCollector?**

Comment: I am sooo lookig forward to the answer to this one! GREAT question!

Comment: Without looking at other code (yours or ASP.NET MVC's..) why exactly do you need to null out the configManager? Does that help anything? Think thoroughly before any of you "DUH" me..

Comment: I mean in a general case like that a race condition can easily be removed like so. In this particular case I doubt that a controller instance would be used by more than one thread and therefore there is no risk of a race condition whatsoever.

Comment: @Andrei: It's just a bit of defensive-coding.  It prevents me from Disposing the Database Connection twice, if my dispose method gets called twice.

Comment: Alright but the Dispose method as defined in the IDisposable interface says clearly that it's safe to be called more than once. And I think all implementors obey this rule.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(VS.71).aspx states clearly that "If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one."

Comment: @Andrei: Well, in my opinion "Ignoring" and "Calling Dispose on Child Objects Anyways" are completely different.  Hence the check.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Dispose is called after the view is rendered, **always**.

The view is rendered in the call to `ActionResult.ExecuteResult`. That's called (indirectly) by `ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction`, which is in turn called by `ControllerBase.ExecuteCore`.

Since the controller is in the call stack when the view is rendered, it cannot be disposed then.

Comment: Great, do you have documentation?  I just want to be sure.

Comment: Great! It'd be great to find a doc explaining it. But expanded answer was really comforting. Code is the better doc at all. :D

Answer (score 37):

Just to expand on [Craig Stuntz's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380019/asp-mvc-when-is-icontroller-dispose-called/1380173#1380173):

The ControllerFactory handles when a Controller is disposed.  When implementing the IControllerFactory interface, one of the methods that needs to be implemented is ReleaseController.

I am not sure what ControllerFactory you are using, whether you rolled your own, but in Reflector looking at the DefaultControllerFactory, the ReleaseController method is implemented like so:

```
public virtual void ReleaseController(IController controller)
{
    IDisposable disposable = controller as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

An IController reference is passed in, if that controller implements IDisposable, then that controllers Dispose method is called.  So, if you have anything you need disposing after the request is finished, which is after the view is rendered.  Inherit off of IDisposable and put your logic in the Dispose method to release any resources.

The ReleaseController method is called by the System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler which handles the request and it implements IHttpHandler.  The ProcessRequest takes the HttpContext given to it and starts the process of finding the controller to handle the request, by calling into the implemented ControllerFactory.  If you look in the ProcessRequest method you will see the finally block which calls the ControllerFactory's ReleaseController.  This is only called when the Controller has returned a ViewResult.

Comment: Awesome answer. I couldn't figure out why a direct instance of a Controller object would not let me call Dispose() on it, but it looks like I need to create a new instance of it using the IDisposable interface. This worked for me!

Comment: So... `HttpContext` is a male? Now I am really confused.