# MVC actual controller vs filterContext.Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have abstract BaseController, which basically looks like below:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IDisposable Resource { get; protected set; }      

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(Resource != null)
        {
            Resource.Dispose();
        }

        var baseController = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;
        if (baseController != null && baseController.Resource != null)
        {
            baseController.Resource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside OnActionExecuted event, I want to dispose Resource object. Is it enough to execute Dispose on Resource ? Do I have to check also for Resource in the Controller from filterContext ?

In debugger in my case that this is the same object, but is it always the same one ? What is it used for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same object.  The `Controller` property can be useful in action filters - they also get an `ActionExecutedContext` in `OnActionExecuted` - and you're not in the controller there.

Answer (score 1):

If it is still the same your controller will be constructed for every request ([ASP.NET MVC Controller Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763775/asp-net-mvc-controller-lifecycle)). Then you could just dispose your resource in the dispose of your controller ([ASP MVC: When is IController Dispose() called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380019/asp-mvc-when-is-icontroller-dispose-called))