# C# .Net_ IDisposable interface

Tags: c#, oop, idisposable

why do we need to implement IDisposable interface when we actually have to write the code for Dispose method. We may write code for clearing managed code without implementing the IDisposable interface? what is the point?

Comment: so that you can put it in `using`, for example. And that consumers of your code have a unified way of knowing to / disposing resources.

Comment: `IDisposable is abstraction` - we don't need it if we have proper, always updated documentation. Then we tell consumers read documentation before using our class :)

Comment: The C# language specification requires that the type implement IDisposable to be used in a `using` statement. Why does the C# specification require that (instead of just calling a method named `Dispose`, like the `foreach` statement only requires a method named `GetEnumerator`)? That's a question only the C# language designers can definitely answer.

Comment: @MichaelLiu the duck-typing of `foreach` allows for direct use of types, producing an indexer on arrays or strings, and was particularly important prior to 2.0 because there was no `IEnumerator<T>`. None of those advantages apply to `Dispose()`.

Comment: There is a great perf gain by having `foreach` not use `IEnumerable<T>` or any other interface, because `Current` and `MoveNext` can be non-virtual + not boxing is required when `GetEnumerator` returns a struct (like e.g. `List<T>` does. None of that applies to `Dispose` + it's only called once and not potentially thousands of times for large collections.

Comment: @JonHanna, @MarcinJuraszek: Sure. But that doesn't explain why C# doesn't **require** `foreach` types to implement IEnumerable—types with performance concerns could do so with an explicit interface implementation. Indeed, if in Jon Hanna's answer you replaced "IDisposable" with "IEnumerable" and "clean-up" with "enumeration", you'd get a good argument to make all enumerable types implement IEnumerable.

Comment: @MichaelLiu yes it does. There are advantages to `foreach` that isn't through `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` so those advantages are made use of (and they were greater before 2.0 so maybe things would be different if generics where in there from day one). There are no advantages to disposal that isn't through `IDisposable` so why make use of advantages that don't exist? Note further that many other uses *do* require `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`, which are usually provided alongside any duck-typed `foreach`.

Comment: @JonHanna: What are those advantages to `foreach`, and why don't they apply to IDisposable? There is in fact a **big** disadvantage to the current C# implementation of the `using` statement: it boxes `struct` instances before calling Dispose, thereby mutating the copy instead of the original.

Comment: @MichaelLiu the lesser one that remains is avoiding boxing, but the biggest one is that it allowed `Current` to return something other than `object`, which can now be done with `IEnumerator<T>` but that didn't exist at the time this was done.

Answer (score 2):

I know the `IDisposable` interface and how to use it already.

When I come to use your class, I'm going to have to learn a few things (which might be really simple, or really complicated) about what it's actually for, but I shouldn't have to learn how to do a clean-up of a sort that many other classes also do, and do through the `IDisposable` interface I already know about.

That's already a big point in favour of having a well-known interface for such use. Another is that it's the best way to have code that works with lots of different types with the common feature of their requiring clean-up. I can write a method that takes `IDisposable thingToDispose` a lot more easily than I can write code that cleans up different objects in different ways according to how each was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

One major advantage of implementing `IDisposable` is being able to use a `using` statement. From the [MSDN page on the `using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

A `using` statement will only accept an `IDisposable`, so if you weren't to implement `IDisposable`, you'd need to create your own logic to ensure `Dispose` is called on your object when exiting the code block which calls methods on your object.

With `IDisposable`:

```
using (var myObject = new MyClass()) {
    ... logic ...
}
```

Without `IDisposable`:

```
{
    var myObject = new MyClass();
    try {
        ... logic ...
    }
    finally {
        myObject.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Above, the `try... finally` pattern ensures that, in the case of an exception being raised, the `Dispose` method is still called, which is a feature you'd have gotten by using `IDisposable` in the `using`. It's also in a self-contained block to ensure `myObject` is not accessed elsewhere after calling `Dispose` – again, a feature of the `using` statement when declaring `myObject` as above.

Answer (score 0):

> We may write code for clearing managed code without implementing the IDisposable interface? what is the point?

Imagine you have this class:

```
public class Bad
{
    private StreamWriter writer;
    public Bad()
    {
        this.writer = new StreamWriter("Bad.txt");
    }
    public void Write(string line)
    {
        writer.Write(line);
    }
}
```

How will you write code for disposing the `writer`? You cannot know from within the class when the client (consumer of your class) will be done with needing it. And the client cannot dispose it because it is `private`. So how will you do it?

You can create another method called `CloseWriter` like this:

```
public void CloseWriter()
{
    this.writer.Dispose();
}
```

And in your documentation you can instruct clients to call this method once they are done with using your class. But the clients will need to read your documentation and sometimes, in some classes this may be called `CloseWriter` and other times it may be called `Done()` or `Finish()`.

The whole idea of implementing the `IDisposable` interface is to have a common language which all clients (developers) are familiar with. Plus they can use the `using` block if you have implemented `IDisposable` interface.

**More Advantages**

There are also more advantages.

1. Class Definition

Your class definition will be like this so other developers will know right away how to properly use your class:

```
public class Good : IDisposable
```

2. Many frameworks, for example, ASP MVC, WCF and others will call the `Dispose` method on your class if it implements `IDisposable`. For example, MVC will call it after the view is [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380019/asp-mvc-when-is-icontroller-dispose-called).

You see without the interface, how will MVC know what method to call: `CloseWriter()`, `Done()`, `Finish()` etc.

3. People will be able to treat your class polymorphically.

   var disposables = new List();
   disposables.Add(new A());
   disposables.Add(new B());
   disposables.Add(new C());

   foreach(var thisDisposable in dispsables)
   {
       thisDisposable.Dispose();
   }

That will work even if `A`, `B`, and `C` are doing completely different things but they all implement `IDisposable` interface.